# Minify javascript in cshtml file asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor, minify

Is there a way to minify the javascript that is within the "@section Scripts" tag in a .cshtml file?

Comment: It would be better if you can add a sample code of what you want to minify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the Asp.net core application using [BuildBundlerMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier) package to bundle and minify static assets (**JavaScript, CSS, and images files**). So, to minify the JavaScript scripts within the `@section Scripts` tag, you have to extract the scripts into an external script file, then using BuildBundlerMinifier to minify the JS file. More detail information about using BuildBundlerMinifier, see [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Besides, you could also try to use some open source package to minify the inline JS. Such as: [WebMarkupMin](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin).

You could install this package via NuGet Package Manager (Based on your application version to select the package version):

[image]

Then, in the Startup.cs file, add `app.UseWebMarkupMin();` and `services.AddWebMarkupMin();` in the Configure and ConfigureServices methods, code as below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddWebMarkupMin(
       options =>
       {
           options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
           options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
       })
       .AddHtmlMinification(
           options =>
           {
               options.MinificationSettings.RemoveRedundantAttributes = true;
               options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpProtocolFromAttributes = true;
               options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpsProtocolFromAttributes = true;
           })
       .AddHttpCompression();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        //Required using WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5;
        app.UseWebMarkupMin();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

After that the JavaScript script has been minified. The screenshot as below:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Well done, TIL bundlerminifier is also a nuget package.  I usually just stick to the bundleconfig.json!

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few options, without more details it's hard to answer which will work best for you.

None of these solutions will parse Razor Syntax, or be able to find your JS code inside a scripts @section block in a cshtml file by themselves. If you need that code minified, you should pull it into a JS file and reference it with a `<script src="..">`

## Options

Visual Studio Tooling: BundlerMinifier. With this tool you can bundle and minify CSS and JS files. Either as a one time operation (right click -> Minify File) or you can create a bundleconfig.json

> Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier

> Note: This tool is included by default with VS 2019, and only needs to be installed via the marketplace on VS 2017 or prior

Other avenues are typically involve NodeJs

- GruntJs (Has some integration with Visual Studio) - https://gruntjs.com/
- GulpJs - https://gulpjs.com/
- Webpack - https://webpack.js.org/